# How to turn string html code into div? in Nuxt js project

Tags: html, nuxt.js

how to display properly for a part of html code?

HTML Code:

```html
<div>{{`<p>_html_data</p>`}}</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var _html_data = `<section>
              <h1 style="color: #5e9ca0;">
                You can edit
                <span style="color: #2b2301;">this demo</span> text!
              </h1>
              <h2 style="color: #2e6c80;">How to use the editor:</h2>
              <p>
                Paste your documents in the visual editor on the left or your HTML code in the source editor in the right.
                <br>Edit any of the two areas and see the other changing in real time.&nbsp;
              </p>
            </section>`;
```

Comment: <div v-html="_html_data"></div>. See [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

Comment: And it's not the best idea . v-html is prone to xss

Comment: hi Andrew1325, thank you so much!!